# Arabic pattern matching in R

Tags: r, unicode, arabic

I have an excel file(original_data.xls) with one column having data in arabic only. I have another text file(keywords.txt) which contains some arabic words. I want to extract only those rows which contains atleast one word from the keywords.txt file. I have tried readLines() and scan() but . It would be quite easy if it were in English but its arabic. As an example, here i want to find if the keywords1 exist in test_data or not.

```
keyword1<- c("الروافض")

test_data <- c("الدولة_الإسلامية لا حول لها ولا قوة إلا بالله وهي مجرد سبب")
```

When i simply used grepl directly, it seemed to work.

```
keywords1 <- "الرافض"
test_data <- c("رافضي","رواف","الرافض")


###[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

EDIT-1
 This is what i have tried. But clean_data2 has no data in it.

```
original_data<-read_excel("original_data.xlsx")

fileName <- "keywords.txt"

conn <- file(fileName,open="r")
linn <-readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
print(linn[i])
  clean_data2 <- clean_data[grep(pattern = paste("\\b", linn[i] , "\\b", sep = ""), x = clean_data$Snippet, fixed = TRUE),]

}
close(conn)
```

Comment: So with grepl you answered your own question?

Comment: Not really, problem is when i import excel and txt file, the arabic strings are not in arabic anymore. Please check my edit.